# java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application error, when testing a class from scala worksheet

Tags: scala, playframework

I wanted to test a class by running it from a scala worksheet. When running this test script:

```
import ping.GcmRestServer

val server = new GcmRestServer("AIzaSyCOn...")
server.send(List("dcGKzDg5VOQ:APA91bHNUDaBj01th..."), Map(
  "message" -> "Test Message",
  "title" -> "Test Title"
))
```

Were the tested class GcmRestServer is

```
package ping

import play.api.Logger
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import play.api.libs.json.Json
/**
  * Created by Lukasz on 26.02.2016.
  */
class GcmRestServer(val key: String) {

  def send(ids: List[String], data: Map[String, String]) = {
    import play.api.Play.current
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    val body = Json.obj(
      "registration_ids" -> ids,
      "data" -> data
    )

    WS.url("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send")
      .withHeaders(
        "Authorization" -> s"key=$key",
        "Content-type" -> "application/json"
      )
      .post(body)
      .map { response => Logger.debug("Result: " + response.body)}
  }
}
```

Gives the following result:

```
import ping.GcmRestServer

server: ping.GcmRestServer = ping.GcmRestServer@34860db2
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
    at scala.sys.package$.error(test.sc2.tmp:23)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(test.sc2.tmp:82)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(test.sc2.tmp:82)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(test.sc2.tmp:117)
    at play.api.Play$.current(test.sc2.tmp:82)
    at ping.GcmRestServer.send(test.sc2.tmp:16)
    at #worksheet#.get$$instance$$res0(test.sc2.tmp:4)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(test.sc2.tmp:19)
```

Could somebody explain me what I did wrong, and how to fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

The line `import play.api.Play.current` requires a running Play application.

I've never used scala worksheets, but it seems the same problem.

On tests, the solution is to run a fake application, as [written in the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTest#Running-in-a-fake-application).

Comment: Could you please give a complete answer instead of an RTFM!

Comment: @AHH i dont have experience running worksheets. I told something similar happens on tests. And I provided the best possible reference where the solution could be explained

Answer (score 0):

You are using play WS which requires a play application running. Just start one with a code like this:

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import play.api.{Play, Mode, DefaultApplication}
import java.io.File
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global



class GcmRestServer(val key: String) {

  val application = new DefaultApplication(
    new File("."),
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
    None,
    Mode.Dev
  )

  def send(ids: List[String], data: Map[String, String]) = {

    val body = Json.obj(
      "registration_ids" -> ids,
      "data" -> data
    )

    WS.client(application).url("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send")
      .withHeaders(
        "Authorization" -> s"key=$key",
        "Content-type" -> "application/json"
      )
      .post(body)
      .map { response => Logger.debug("Result: " + response.body)}
  }
}
```

Or if you don't want to use `WS.Client(application)` you may run `Play.start(application)`, import it with `import play.api.Play.current`  and then `WS.url` will work.